# Excel VBA Extract rows and paste as value

Tags: excel, vba, datatables, extract

Good evening,

I'm trying to extract data from a table based on a cellvalue and then paste it as values ​​into the other worksheet.

the code from the Internet is as followed:

```
Sub Rubbisch()
        Dim xRg As Range
        Dim xCell As Range
        Dim i As Long
        Dim J As Long
        Dim K As Long
        i = Worksheets("DATA").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        J = Worksheets("uitzonderingen").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If J = 1 Then
           If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Boven_500").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
        End If
        Set xRg = Worksheets("DATA").Range("S1:S" & i)
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For K = 1 To xRg.Count
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "YES" Then
                xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Boven_500").Range("A" & J + 1)
                
                xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
                If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "YES" Then
                    K = K - 1
                End If
                J = J + 1
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
            End Sub
```

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're facing?  Don't ask us to guess.  When deleting rows it's best to work from the bottom up so `For K = xRg.Count To 1 Step -1`  Modifying the loop counter in a For..Next loop is a bad practise.

Comment: Take out the `On Error Resume Next` - Do you get an error?

Comment: I don't get an error, it moves the rows to antother sheet but it pastes the formulas and I would like to move them as values

Comment: you can select your new range and re-copy them, then paste them as value

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LessRubbisch()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or (eg) ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets("DATA")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Boven_500")
    'find last-used row number on destination sheet and add 1
    i = wsDest.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For j = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1 'step backwards
        With wsSrc.Cells(j, "S")
            If .Value = "YES" Then
                wsDest.Rows(i).Value = .EntireRow.Value 'copy values
                .EntireRow.Delete                  'delete source row
                i = i + 1                          'next destination row
            End If
        End With
    Next j
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: OP: this should also work faster as you're not copy pasting. As for the reason why deleting backwards is better, it's because if you delete a row, but you go next j, then you're skipping the row that became the same row number as the deleted one, i.e. delete row 3 -> row 4 becomes row 3 -> next j = 4 = (original) row 4 skipped. @Tim: that sub name though :')

Comment: @Notus_Panda - that's the "improved" version of the original name  